# Create a graph image (png, jpg ..) from an XML file with Java

Tags: java, xml, image, graph

I have an XML file and I want to create a graph based on some entities, then store this graph in an image, JPG or PNG.

So is there a library in Java to do something like this? Or are there some tricks by parsing XML files?

Here an example
XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<process>
  <p n="1">Tove</p> 
  <p n="2">Jani</p> 
  <p n="2">Bill</p> 
  <p n="4">John</p> 
</process>
```

And the output will be like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems that http://www.graphviz.org/ provides already what You'll willing to implement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extract the names using one of the myriad of Java XML libraries. Here's an example using XPath from a [Java DOM](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html):

```
private static List<String> findNames(Document doc)
                                           throws XPathExpressionException {
  XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
  NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/process/p", doc, 
                                                    XPathConstants.NODESET);
  List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    names.add(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
  }
  return names;
}
```

*Note: it may be a typo, but your XML is not well formed - attribute values must be quoted. XML parsing will fail otherwise.*

[image: some boxes]

You can use the [AWT API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) to draw whatever you want:

```
private static final int BORDER = 1;
private static final int PADDING = 2;
private static final int SPACER = 5;

private static void draw(Graphics2D g, List<String> names) {
  FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
  Rectangle box = new Rectangle(1, 1, 0, 0);
  box.height = metrics.getHeight() + (PADDING * 2);
  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  for (String name : names) {
    box.width = metrics.stringWidth(name) + (PADDING * 2);
    g.drawString(name, box.x + BORDER + PADDING, PADDING + BORDER +
                                                    metrics.getHeight());
    g.drawRect(box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height);
    box.x += box.width + (BORDER * 2) + SPACER;
  }
}
```

This code just draws the names with some boxes around them. I'm sure my offsets are all over the place, but you probably get the idea.

There is an [imageio API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) that can save in a few popular data formats:

```
private static void save(List<String> names, File file) throws IOException {
  BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(600, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
  try {
    draw(g, names);
  } finally {
    g.dispose();
  }
  ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I found a class in java that's corporate with GraphViz to extraxt a picture in the end after parsing the XML file and and output a GraphViz representation http://www.loria.fr/~szathmar/off/projects/java/GraphVizAPI/index.php#history

Answer (score 6):

I'd parse the XML and output a Graphviz DOT representation like this:

```
digraph {
  Tove -> Jani
  Jani -> Bill
  Bill -> John
}
```

Then I'd call the Graphviz dot executable from Java using ProcessRunner:

```
dot -Tpng -o file.png file.dot
```

See http://graphviz.org for further info.

Answer (score 0):

I found a java **class** that works great with **GraphViz** to create an image after parsing the XML file and output a GraphViz representation. [Follow this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110203014912/http://www.loria.fr/%7Eszathmar/off/projects/java/GraphVizAPI/index.php) for more information.